# Creating a contact with a custom record type from a household

Tags: contact, record-type, create-records, households

I have a set of custom record types for Contacts. From the Manage Household function, I would like to create a Contact record with an ability to choose one of the custom record types for Contacts.

How should I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you've went throught the [Manage Household Accounts](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/constituent-data-management-with-nonprofit-success-pack/manage-household-accounts) Trailhead module.

It looks to me like there's only one Contact Record Type allowed for each Household. If you create a contact with a different record type, it may just split that contact into [its own seperate Household](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8eP4SAJ).

Here's a somewhat [related question](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000J5fbnSAB).You'll get the best answers if you post in the [Nonprofit Hub Group](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F9300000001ocxCAA?tab=discussion&sort=LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_DESC) where the second link was pulled from.

Comment: Thank you. I've posted the question in the group you suggested. The trailhead module doesn't address the question, but I appreciate you identifying it for others that may read this.